How to save version as * or latest or x in package.json created by script
I'm adapting a script that sets up all the files needed for a new component in a repo full of components. It uses the command
`npx lerna add --dev LOCAL_TOOLS_PACKAGE --scope=${newComponentPackageName}`

to make sure every new component's package.json has the LOCAL_TOOLS_PACKAGE in devDependencies.
I want it to result in
  "devDependencies": {
    "LOCAL_TOOLS_PACKAGE": "*"
  },

because all these local components need to use the latest version of LOCAL_TOOLS_PACKAGE even if it's a major change, and no one needs to have to go through and update their package.jsons by hand if there is a breaking change in LOCAL_TOOLS_PACKAGE.
But I can't find a way to get that from the command line; no matter what I try it's always delivering the version as "LOCAL_TOOLS_PACKAGE": "^3.4.1"

I happened to be able to ask @ljharb about this and he said that it was not possible to do via npm install, but it could be done using npm pkg set
So if I wanted to add, using a script, "meow" at version "*" to a package.json, I could do:
npm install --save meow && npm pkg set "dependencies.meow"="*"

This works.
